# RaiseError on SQL Server stored procedures

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, raiserror

```
ALTER PROCEDURE sp1
as
begin
IF (@PersonId=0)
    RAISERROR(N'Error already raised. See previous errors.', 16, 1);
    break
end
```

I want something like the following.

If no value in the variable, how to break the procedure in SQL Server?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to raise error and exit from the procedure, you may want to try `return`. Example below.

```
alter PROCEDURE sp1
@PersonID int
as
begin
   IF (@PersonId is null)  --you can check 0, if that is the intention
   begin
       RAISERROR(N'Error already raised. See previous errors.', 16, 1);
       return;
   end;
   print '@PersonId is not null';  --Condition when error is not raised
end;
```

Comment: From a stored procedure you can return an integer value e.g. `return -3;`, which can be interrogated by the caller to take appropriate action.  SPs also support `OUT` parameters for returning values to the caller.